# Failed to resolve all androidx libraries

Tags: java, android

I've added the library for the Room database. It was a androidX library. I didn't know a lot about libraries (I am a beginner) and also didn't know about AndroidX. I got these manifest merger errors and while resarching for a solution, I found out about the AndroidX libraries. So I wanted to migrate my project to AndroidX, but Android Studio can't resolve any of these libraries.

My build gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.financetracker.financetracker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

My build gradle(Project):

```
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.financetracker.financetracker">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.HomeActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you set useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true in your gradle settings?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these in your project `build.gradle` file,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin DSL

```
repositories {
    maven { setUrl("https://maven.google.com") }
}
```